# Effecient way to read and store image via Servlet (avoiding DoS)

Tags: java, servlets, denial-of-service

A image file will be sent to a servlet POST method.
I need to Read the request input stream and store it as image in server  .
I thought of using BufferedImage and ImageIO classes .
But im Afraid of DoS attack .

Any suggestions would be helpful .

Thanks

Comment: is it open service or guarded by any kind of authentication, use a some kind of proxy server

Comment: @silentsudo It is authenticated . Any best practice for the above scenario ?

Comment: see nginx and hxproxy have them before you server and need not worry much keep internal server flexible